# Mongo Gandi SSL certificate not trusted

Tags: mongodb, ssl, trusted

I have a problem on MongoDB for using the SSL mode.
When I trying to connect on my database, I have this error.

```
mongo --ssl --sslCAFile /etc/ssl/certs/GandiStandardSSLCA2.pem  --host plip.plop.com

MongoDB shell version: 3.0.6
connecting to: plip.plop.com:27017/test
2015-10-16T10:24:23.122+0000 E NETWORK  SSL peer certificate validation failed:certificate not trusted
2015-10-16T10:24:23.126+0000 E QUERY    Error: socket exception [CONNECT_ERROR] for
at connect (src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:181:14)
at (connect):1:6 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:181
```

my server respond:

```
2015-10-16T10:26:53.034+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 172.17.0.227:48786 #1 (1 connection now open)
2015-10-16T10:26:53.046+0000 W NETWORK  [conn1] no SSL certificate provided by peer
2015-10-16T10:26:53.046+0000 I NETWORK  [conn1] end connection 172.17.0.227:48786 (0 connections now open)
```

( In can connect to my db if I use the flag `--sslAllowInvalidCertificates` )

---

So now, how I do that:

I have added SSL cert with this code:

```
cp wildcart.plop.com.crt /etc/ssl/certs/wildcart.plop.com.crt
cp wildcart.plop.com.key /etc/ssl/private/wildcart.plop.com.key
cp GandiStandardSSLCA2.pem /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/gandi.net /GandiStandardSSLCA2.crt # come from https://wiki.gandi.net/en/ssl/intermediate
cat /etc/ssl/private/wildcart.plop.com.key /etc/ssl/certs/wildcart.plop.com.crt > /etc/ssl/certs/mongodb.pem
rm /etc/ssl/private/wildcart.plop.com.key /etc/ssl/certs/wildcart.plop.com.crt
update-ca-certificates
c_rehash
```

and my mongodb is start with this line `mongod --replSet plop --config /etc/mongodb/mongod`

`/etc/mongodb/mongod` content:

```
net:
    ssl:
        mode: requireSSL
        PEMKeyFile: /etc/ssl/certs/mongodb.pem
        CAFile: /etc/ssl/certs/GandiStandardSSLCA2.pem
        allowConnectionsWithoutCertificates: true
```

---

So can you help me on this problem ? I don't understand why my certificate isn't trusted.
Do you have any idea on that ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

PS: Sorry for my english, I'm not totally fluent in english :D

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/80859/issues-with-self-signed-certificates-ssl-and-mongodb

Comment: It's not exactly the same case. I don't want to authenticate the client with a certificate. For the moment, I don't use any password or key for the client. I just want to connect on mongo through ssl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongodb doesn't use the system's global trust store.

The sslCAFile must contains all intermediary certificates of the verification chain.

In my case the certificate chain is like that:

```
Certificate chain
 0 s:/OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=Gandi Standard Wildcard SSL/CN=*.plop.com
   i:/C=FR/ST=Paris/L=Paris/O=Gandi/CN=Gandi Standard SSL CA 2
 1 s:/C=FR/ST=Paris/L=Paris/O=Gandi/CN=Gandi Standard SSL CA 2
   i:/C=US/ST=New Jersey/L=Jersey City/O=The USERTRUST Network/CN=USERTrust RSA Certification Authority
 2 s:/C=US/ST=New Jersey/L=Jersey City/O=The USERTRUST Network/CN=USERTrust RSA Certification Authority
   i:/C=SE/O=AddTrust AB/OU=AddTrust External TTP Network/CN=AddTrust External CA Root
```

So you need to concat Gandi intermediary certificates with AddTrust External CA Root  intermediary certificates.

```
cat /etc/ssl/certs/GandiStandardSSLCA2.pem /ets/ssl/certs/AddTrust_External_Root.pem > /ets/ssl/certs/GandiStandardSSLCA2_full.pem

mongo --ssl --sslCAFile /ets/ssl/certs/GandiStandardSSLCA2_full.pem --host plip.plop.com
```

Enjoy

Comment: Why doesn't it use the global trust store?